# Form a block diagonal matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to form a 100x100 block diagonal matrix whose diagonal entities are 5, ((2k-1)2k) and (2k(2k-1)) entities are the same as 0.5 for k = 1,2,...50, and all other entities are zero.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want here, can you give a small example of what you are after? And what you have tried?

Comment: each of the block matrix will be 2x2 matrix ' matrix(c(5, 0.5, 0.5, 5), 2, 2)' and all other entities of 100x100 block diagonal matrix are 0.

Answer (score 3):

With `base R`, you can achieve it via using `kronecker()` to creat block-diagonal matrix, i.e.,

```
M <- kronecker(diag(50),matrix(c(5,0.5,0.5,5),2,2))
```

Comment: This fails for me: `Error in 'dimnames<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', value = list(n)) : invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame`

Comment: @Earlien it is for matrix, not for dataframe

Comment: All I'm saying is the code you've suggested `kronecker(diag(50),matrix(c(5,0.5,0.5,5),2,2))` literally gives me that error.

Comment: @Earlien I cannot reproduce the error you said. it worked well in my machine

Comment: Strange. I tried it again today and it worked.  Must be have been a weird package mix-up.

Answer (score 1):

```
> library(Matrix)
> M <- as.matrix(bdiag(lapply(seq_len(50), function(X) matrix(c(5, 0.5, 0.5, 5), 2))))
> dim(M)
```